# How to preserve attachment content between render passes

Tags: vulkan

I have multiple "renderers" which should draw to the same attachment (swap chain image to be precise). I don't know the number of such renderers beforehand so I can't use subpasses. This is how I wanted to implement it:

```
VkCommandBuffer cb{...}; // get current "main" command buffer
for(auto r : renderers)
{
    VkRenderPassBeginInfo renderPassBeginInfo{get_render_pass_begin_info(...)};
    vkCmdBeginRenderPass(cb, &renderPassBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS);
    array<VkCommandBuffer, 2> buffs{r->getCommandBuffers()}; // renderer build two secondary command buffers...
    vkCmdExecuteCommands(cb, 1, buffs[0]); // first should be used in a render pass
    vkCmdEndRenderPass(cb);
    vkCmdExecuteCommands(cb, 1, buffs[1]); // second should be used ooutside of a render pass
}
```

The problem here is that each new call to `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` clears the target. This happens because the attachment was created with `loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR` because I need to clear it (but only once).

The solution in my case would be to move `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` and `vkCmdEndRenderPass` outside of the loop, but in this case, I need to "collect" all secondary command buffers that can't be used inside a render pass and execute them later.

But since the concept of render passes doesn't go into my head I wonder if there may be a way to keep the attachment's data between render passes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stop clearing the attachments on load. Just manually clear them, either before the render pass begins or at the start of the first subpass.

That being said, render passes are not cheap, and this is really not the way to use them. The correct solution is to restructure your rendering code so that you only need a single render pass.

Comment: Thank you. You're right - there are `vkCmdClearColorImage` and `vkCmdClearAttachments` commands. But I didn't understand your second sentence - I'm using a single primary command buffer. But multiple secondary buffers.

Comment: @nikitablack it is very likely that you don't need to switch renderpasses (or even subpasses) at all. Double check what actually changes between renderers and see if you can unify it all.

Comment: @ratchetfreak the thing is that I need to alternate inside-render-pass commands with outside-render-pass ones. For example, for one "renderer", I need to record a draw command (inside render pass) followed by set event command (outside).

Comment: @nikitablack: Is a later rendering operation going to wait on that event? Is there some reason it cannot use a normal barrier instead?

Comment: @nikitablack does the event need to be set right after the render or can you delay that? Loading and unloading the framebuffer is not cheap and it's more efficient to first bang out all renders and then set the event or use a normal barrier.

Comment: The event is used to check render complete on the cpu. By some reasons I can't use fences, you can read the related question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vulkan/comments/8lrvlb/single_host_visible_buffer_multiple/). But as I wrote in the main question I can execute all draw command buffers in the same render pass and set my events imediately afterwards.

Comment: @nikitablack: Why does the CPU need to know when each rendering operation has completed, rather than just waiting until the batch or submit is done (via the semaphore or fence)? Basically, you're designing your application wrong.

Comment: @NicolBolas I need to write to a host-visible vertex buffer and the host needs to know when a buffer is "free" (i have multiple of them). I can't use fences because of a framework limitations. Though I'm not excluding that the design is wrong, I think I'm on the right way - I already spent days thinking and testing. The application is very specific and there's no common scenario for such cases. But anyway, any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: @nikitablack: "*I need to write to a host-visible vertex buffer and the host needs to know when a buffer is "free"*" That's what semaphores and fences are for. And if you have a "framework limitation" that prevents you from using fences, then that's a limitation that needs to be *solved*.

Comment: @NicolBolas in my case the framework is Qt. It's huge and complex, that's why I can't easily solve the limitation.

Comment: @nikitablack: I don't know how Qt uses Vulkan, but if it's not letting you directly submit batches to Vulkan (which would be the only reason you couldn't use fences), then I would suggest abandoning it.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, submitting is done inside the library and not exposed to the outside. And thank you for the opinion - I'll use it as argument in future discussions at my work.